# Can anyone suggest eclipse tool to analyse java memory usage

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-management

Can anyone suggest eclipse tool to analyze java memory usage.

I am working on developing java application using eclipse RCP. I want to analyze memory use, memory leaks, and other memory related issue using some smart tool which will give me graphical representation in eclipse itself.

I am using jre 1.7.0.25 for development.

I tried using [memory analyzer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer#Getting_a_Heap_Dump) but it is not showing me either perspective or views to analyze the memory.

Comment: Does it have to be an eclipse tool?

Comment: @Joni If it is, It would be great. or you can suggest me other tools I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to work with the combination of 2 tools for finding memory problems

1) [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to get an overview

2) [MemoryAnalyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to find memory leaks. You can analyze thread dump, created with VisualVm.

Comment: I am using eclipse 3.8 jre is 1.7.0.25 and OS is windows 7 64bit. I tried installing eclipse.org/mat but not able to view the perspective or view for the this plugin.

Comment: The tool is a standalone version. No need to integrate it into eclipse. You can start it directly with 'MemoryAnalyzer.exe'

Answer (score 3):

I use Java VisualVM. It is a standard tool and should be already installed if you installed JDK.

You can find in in `{JDK_INSTALLATION}\bin\jvisualvm.exe` if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using JVisualVM, which is part of the JDK distributions, not as an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/) which is integrated into Eclipse and is similar to JVisualVM (with less features).

Comment: I tried installing it from eclipse but I am not able to view the Java Monitor perspective after installing from http://www.jvmmonitor.org/download/index.html. I am using eclipse 3.8 jre is 1.7.0.25 and OS is windows 7 64bit. Even I tried installing http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ also but not able to view the perspective or view for the respective plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try visualVM (withing jdk installation) or jProfiler.